# Displaying paragraph properly inside mui box element on React

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a react template which is using MUI in a box component.

Trying to edit the attributes of a Box element to display the proper content but it only has 2 attributes (title/subtitle).

I need to divide the subtitle attribute into multiple lines to display the content properly but when trying to insert a paragraph and do it like so

```js
          {
            title: 'Title',
            subtitle:
              `${string1}` + <br></br> + `${string2}`,
          },
```

I get the result `string1[object Object]string2`

Is there any way to create a paragraph inside the subtitle attribute that allows me to display the  text properly without creating new attributes?

Comment: Can you include your Box component, i don't get where title and subtitle come from

Comment: You mean a List component not a Box? A Box doesn't have any title or subtitle props.